# Group concat per row by getting all table results

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, group-concat

For my search index I need to create an sql to get serval table results.

For example, I have the following tables;

- tags (in this table I get all the tags)
- video_tags (in this table I get video_id's related to a tag id)
- videos (all videos)

When I want to get a movie with tags I use the follow query;

```
SELECT 
  videos.id,
  videos.id AS video_id,
  videos.video_title AS video_title,
  Group_Concat(DISTINCT t.tag_name SEPARATOR '|') AS tag_names 
FROM videos
JOIN video_tags AS vt ON vt.video_id = videos.id 
JOIN tags AS t ON t.tag_id = vt.tag_id 
WHERE videos.id = '10'
```

This works perfect for me.

Now I need to take all the results from the table by something like this;

```
SELECT 
  videos.id,
  videos.id AS video_id,
  videos.video_title AS video_title,
  Group_Concat(DISTINCT t.tag_name SEPARATOR '|') AS tag_names 
FROM videos
JOIN video_tags AS vt ON vt.video_id = videos.id 
JOIN tags AS t ON t.tag_id = vt.tag_id 
WHERE videos.id <=( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )
```

The problem I am facing here Is how I use the group_concat function. It combines all the rows
into one single row (what I can understand). My question is, how do I use the group_concat function to put all tag results into a single field but PER row.

e.g. result now

```
id | video_id | video_title | tag_names
 1       1      title of id1   all tag_names from tags
```

What I want

```
 id | video_id | video_title | tag_names
 1       1      title of id1   tags fort this row 
 2       2      title of id2   tags fort this row
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT videos.id,
       videos.id AS video_id,
       videos.video_title AS video_title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag_name SEPARATOR '|') AS tag_names 
FROM   videos
JOIN   video_tags AS vt
ON     vt.video_id = videos.id 
JOIN   tags AS t
ON     t.tag_id = vt.tag_id 
WHERE  videos.id <=
       (
       SELECT  max_doc_id
       FROM    sph_counter
       WHERE   counter_id = 1
       )
GROUP BY
       videos.id
```

Comment: perfect! The group by of course :) thanks a lot will accept when I can